# MvvmCross Using a modal ViewController from a Tab

Tags: xamarin.ios, modal-dialog, viewcontroller, mvvmcross

I've searched on SO & elsewhere for MvvmCross & Modal, but the one existing answer isn't helping us.

We're developing a cross-platform app using MonoTouch & MvvmCross, which seems to be pretty powerful combination. However, we're having a few issues with the navigation, which we're gradually cracking! The current problem is -

The app runs with a TabBarController, and each tab has navigation to further levels - this works fine. The client however wants the "Start" button on one of the tabs to bring up a modal view (which hides everything else, especially the tab bar), which then has its own levels working in the same manner as a UINavigationController, with the ability to pop back to the tabBarController at any time.

We've managed to bring up a single modal view, but we're stuck on loading new views from here and popping back out.

Any help/advice appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're looking to do is to customise the presenter so that it wraps your  UIViewController within a UINavigationController - and then modally presents that UINavigationController?

To achieve this, the code in the recent Pull request from @DeapSquatter might help -https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/pull/9 - I think you can use his [modal nav presenter](https://github.com/deapsquatter/MvvmCross/blob/49a7a135bfd8d4f4ea211ce791816eac36a379be/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Touch/Views/Presenters/MvxModalNavSupportTouchViewPresenter.cs)  in order to achieve the effect you are looking for:

```
        if (view is IMvxModalTouchView)
        {
            if (_currentModalViewController != null)
                throw new MvxException("Only one modal view controller at a time supported");

            var newNav = new UINavigationController();
            newNav.PushViewController(view as UIViewController, false);

            _currentModalViewController = view as UIViewController;

            PresentModalViewController(newNav, true);
            return;
        }
```

The architecture of mvvmcross is deliberately extensible and configurable here - while we include a few basic Presenter classes, it's very likely that people are going to want to customise how different views get presented on an app-by-app basis. Beyond the simplest of demo apps, I anticipate that most mvvmcross apps on touch will ship with a custom presenter inside.

Hope that helps

Stuart

Comment: Thanks very much for this - I'm not going to get a chance to try it out till after the weekend, but I'll keep you updated.

Comment: I've been modifying the presenter now I can see how it's used - DeepSquatter's example was a major help in finally figuring out what was going on. When our project is further advanced & I'm certain it does what it's meant to do, I'll upload the code in case anyone might find it useful. Thanks!

Comment: If, like us, you encounter a situation where the viewmodel show code runs but nothing is displayed visually, double check that your Presenter's CurrentTopViewController is what you expect it to be. We had to override the Presenter's property "CurrentTopViewController" in order for the correct view to be presenting the modal view.