# why does MvxModalSupportTouchViewPresenter in MvvmCross only support one modal view

Tags: xamarin.ios, modal-dialog, mvvmcross

I have an application that needs a model view on top of a modal view but the presenter MvxModalSupportTouchViewPresenter doesn't support it. Is there any reason for this before I set out on extending it?

Answer (score 0):

The default mvx presenters are there to provide basic presentation. If you need custom functionality then please do create your own presenter logic. See the conference sample for an example - ir reroutes navigation through a tab controller.

I anticipate that many phone and especially tablet apps will make their own presenters.

---

Please also see the recent discussion on showing a navigation bar within the modal presentation - [MvvmCross Using a modal ViewController from a Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037119/mvvmcross-using-a-modal-viewcontroller-from-a-tab)

---

Hope that helps

Stuart