# MvvmCross and MonoTouch: remove top bar

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross to create a MonoTouch application. I have followed the the [basic tutorial](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Tutorial-Part-1), and so far so good. The only problem is that my (initial and so far only) view is displayed with a top bar/navigation bar, which I don't want. I am able to hide the navigation bar by calling

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true;
```

in the view controller's ViewDidLoad. I would prefer to not have to suppress the navigation bar, but rather that it not be there at all. The fact that it is appearing is suggesting that perhaps I am doing something wrong/inheriting from the wrong base classes?

Further details on my code:

The view controller inherits from `MvxBindingTouchViewController`.

My Setup class inherits from `MvxBaseTouchBindingSetup` (I will not be using TouchDialog anywhere, so am not inheriting from `MvxTouchDialogBindingSetup`).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! If I need to supply more details on my code, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The Navigation bar is part of the UINavigationController which is used in the default Presenter.

The Presenter is the thing that decides how a View (a UIViewController) is shown - whether it is displayed in a popup, displayed as a Modal view, pushed into a navigation controller, etc.

If you want to customise the Presenter - e.g. so that it hides the navigation bar - then just switch in your own implementation in your AppDelegate.cs where you find the code:

```
        // initialize app for single screen iPhone display
        var presenter = new MvxTouchViewPresenter(this, _window);
        var setup = new Setup(this, presenter);
        setup.Initialize();
```

You can see some examples of custom presenters in the TwitterSearch and Conference samples. TwitterSearch uses different presenters for phone vs tablet; and Conference uses a presenter which is aware of multiple tabs, each of which contains a NavigationController.

There are also a few other questions around on custom presenters like [MvvmCross Using a modal ViewController from a Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037119/mvvmcross-using-a-modal-viewcontroller-from-a-tab) and [why does MvxModalSupportTouchViewPresenter in MvvmCross only support one modal view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041605/why-does-mvxmodalsupporttouchviewpresenter-in-mvvmcross-only-support-one-modal-v/)

Comment: Thanks Stuart, will try out your suggestions!