# MvvmCross application freezes and crashes when re-showing modal view model

Tags: crash, xamarin.ios, modal-dialog, mvvmcross

The app I'm working on consists of a hierarchy of data and a filter to search through that data. The data is displayed in a hierarchy of table views, and navigation through that hierarchy works fine. However, when I try to navigate to my filter view model (which is shown as a modal view controller), I run into problems.

The first time I open the modal view, everything works fine, and I can close it and all navigation still works. When I try to open it a second time, however, the modal view will appear and the app will freeze and crash after a couple of seconds.

Here is the code from my custom presenter (which is a subclass of MvxModalSupportTouchViewPresenter) that is handling the modal navigation request:

```
public override void Show (IMvxTouchView view)
{
    if (view is IMvxModalTouchView) {
    var newNav = new UINavigationController ();
    newNav.PushViewController (view as UIViewController, false);
    newNav.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.Black;
    PresentModalViewController (newNav, true);
    return;
...
```

(taken from [MvvmCross Using a modal ViewController from a Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037119/mvvmcross-using-a-modal-viewcontroller-from-a-tab))

I close the modal by dismissing it in the view itself. Does anyone have any idea why the app is crashing?

Comment: Is this on simulator and real device? Can you check the console output - does that say anything about the crash? If you don't use modal, or don't use your custom presenter, then does it still crash?

Comment: This happens on the simulator, but there is no console output that indicates why it crashed. The output is simply:

Navigation: Diagnostic:  14.22 Navigate to FiltersViewModel with args
TouchNavigation: Diagnostic:  14.22 Navigate requested

Comment: In that case you'll need to debug more - try adding more trace and/or removing line by line from the view and viewmodel code - until you identify which line is causing the crash (which I suspect might eleven be an infinite loop leading to a stack overflow?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow up on this by email was...

> "As to my previous question, I found where the error was. The view
>   associated with my modal view model got into an infinite loop of
>   Dispose() calls. It would only happen if the modal was shown multiple
>   times. Commenting out the Dispose() method allowed me to open it
>   multiple times."

Not sure currently whether this was a fault in the mvx framework or in the app code - but thought I'd post this here in case it helps others